# Gearbox Joint operation

Tags: gazebo-7

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hello everyone,

I am trying to use the gearbox joint. I found a world [example](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/src/5d1cb7767586834bc7df07a003a0be9c4c03db7b/sdf/worlds/gearbox.world?at=ode_gearbox&fileviewer=file-view-default) but it seems to be outdated, as the parameters have been renamed, from *gear_ratio* and *reference_body* to *gearbox_ratio* and *gearbox_reference_body* respectively. However I cannot get it to work, and I do not know if it is my setup's fault, as I am not sure I have understood the way it works correctly, or if it just not supported anymore.

In the case that it is not, does someone have an idea how to transmit motion and torque from a joint to another ?

Thank you all for your time.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/16172/gearbox-joint-operation/) by [SprGrf](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2885/sprgrf/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 23 on 2017-05-16

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

There's a model with a gearbox joint here https://github.com/osrf/gazebo_models/blob/master/demo_joint_types/model.sdf

The gearbox joint is more of a constraint between two joints rather than a true joint. Create two revolute joints: one for the input link and one for the output link. On the gearbox joint `<parent>` specifies the input link, and `<child>` specifies the output link. `<gearbox_ratio>` is the ratio of the input and output. `<gearbox_reference_body>` is another link that is fixed relative to the input and output. The physics engine measures the velocity of the input and output link relative to this link when enforcing the gear ratio.

---

Originally posted by [sloretz](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1290/sloretz/) with karma: 558 on 2017-05-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [SprGrf](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2885/sprgrf/) on 2017-05-17**:
Thanks for the immediate reply. That was exactly what I was looking for. Thank you very much.